# In Android when return to previous activity black background/shadow retun instead of image in the activity

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have two activities.

1. Activity A (First Activity) with image view.
2. Activity B

In **Activity A** (First Activity) there is an `imageview`.

[Activity A](http://i1289.photobucket.com/albums/b509/salikclub/StackOverFlow/7a22f817-9527-4883-8524-92d865f63c09_zps0d66a899.jpg)

I take a photo from camera and passed that image to next activity - Activity B.

After that, when I return to the previous activity (Activity A) using `backbutton` the content of image is not shown clearly. On the image there was a black **shadow/ background**. Not only the image view the shadow is shown **almost 2/3 of the screen**.

[Activity A - By pressing back button](http://i1289.photobucket.com/albums/b509/salikclub/StackOverFlow/065289c0-4f90-4b44-b7bc-82d909e7a6c7_zps66c6c9ef.jpg)

Can anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: need more details, please describe  image is not shown clearly.

Comment: Hi Manishpro, Thanks for the reply. I edited the question. Please see the images. Thanks

Comment: post your code of activity B